# Login to Plotly from R

Tags: r, authentication, plotly, r-plotly

Can I log into Plotly from R? By putting in my credentials as follows

```
py <- plotly("myusername", "blah")
```

to open the connection, my graphs do not show up unless I go to the Plotly website and log in as well. I want a way to log into Plotly directly from R without going to the website.

Comment: R is not a web browser.

Comment: If you use RStudio (even the free version) then the plots will appear in its viewer tab. Also, you won't need to login nor to specify your plotly api key.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you run the Enterprise version of RStudio, you can have your plotly plot open in the Viewer tab.